# code with array subscript references and pointer dereferencing compiles and runs but the results are unexpected

Tags: c, loops, pointers

Why this program can compiling and run but the result is out of my expectation?`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *message="hello";
    for(int i=0;*message!='\0';i++)
    {
        printf("%c",message[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this one can meet my expection.(print "hello" rightly)

```
int main(void)
{
    char *message="hello";
    for(int i=0;*message!='\0';i++)
    {
        printf("%c",*message++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the C language,arr[i] is equal to *arr.But in the cases I show above,the result is totally different,when I run them in the devc++.Due to my limited knowledge ,I can't understand this.

Because I'm a student who is going to be a freshman after this summer vacation and only have some konwledge about C language,please answer my question in a more acceptable way. Thanks in advance!

***sorry ,the problem is caused because of my carelessness.I have learned my mistake.

Comment: `*message != '\0'` is always false because `message` is never modified. So what do you expect? `*message!='\0'` -> `message[i] !='\0'`

Comment: `*message!='\0'` Think about how that can ever become false considering `message` doesn't change in the loop. That is, that always checks the first character in the string which in this case is never NUL - hence infinete loop (and likely eventually crash)

Comment: @zhm It is very evident what is the difference. So the question does not  make a sense and should be closed.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code, the pointer `message` isn't changed and what the pointer `message` points at is also not changed, so the condition `*message!='\0'` is always true (doing `'h'!='\0'`).

Therefore, `i` will continuously be incremented and become so large that `message[i]` goes out of a region where access is allowed.

The condition should be `message[i]!='\0'` to avoid this error.

If you want to stick to use `*` operator for some reason, it should be `*(message+i)!='\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

> In the C language, arr[i] is equal to *arr....

No, `*arr` is equal to `arr[0]`.

In your first example, you type `message++` which make et points on the next character.

So, the first code can be corrected that way:

```c
    for(int i=0; message[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",message[i]);
    }
```

And the second can be simplified: (you don't need `i`):

```c
    for( ;*message!='\0'; )
    {
        printf("%c",*message++);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite the program with a *slightly* different appearance

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *message="hello";
    for(int i=0; 'h'!='\0';i++) // notice the change here
    {
        printf("%c",message[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You see the problem now?

`*message` is always `h`, it's not changing with the loop iteration. The comparison is meaningless here, it does not terminate the loop as expected.

You need to ensure that you change the pointer to the next address every time you iterate, to ensure you are checking the value of the next element.

You can make use of the index value, like

```
 for(int i=0; * (message + i) !='\0';i++)
```